# How to animate gradient offset using Velocity.js

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate, gradient, offset, velocity.js

I want to animate gradient to "move" right and in order to do so i have to animate offset property of stop element, but right now i'm only succeeding to animate stop-color property.

```
<linearGradient id="gr-simple" x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="0%">
<stop id = "first"  stop-color="lightblue" offset="10%"/>
<stop id = "second" stop-color="red" offset="90%"/>
</linearGradient>
```

Works:

```
$("#first")
        .delay(1500)
        .velocity({stopColor: "#FF4E50" },{duration:1500});
```

Does not work:

```
$("#first")
        .delay(1500)
        .velocity({offset: "50%"},{duration:1500});
```

Any help i can get is much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

was looking for the same thing and stumbled upon this pen :
http://codepen.io/jorgeatgu/pen/niubs?editors=101

The trick seems to be using x1, x2, y1 and y2 values :

```
            <linearGradient id="background" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
            <stop id="one" offset="0%" stop-color="crimson"/>
            <stop id="two" offset="100%" stop-color="cyan"/>
        </linearGradient>
```

and in your js :

```
$("#background")
        .delay(500)
        .velocity({x2: "100%", y2: "0%" },{duration:1500, easing: "linear"})
```

I don't know yet about those properties but you should be able to find some docs !

PS : be sure to animate the colors on the `<stop>` and the offsets on the `<linearGradient>`

Hope this helps ! (even if I'm probably too late)

Loic

EDIT :

Actually I think animating offset ***should work***, but it doesn't, so I guess moving the whole gradient around using x1/x2/y1/y2 values is an option, it did what I wanted